# Can someone explain this es6 syntax to me?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Can someone explain the following statement?

```
  return state.map(todo =>
    (todo.id === action.id)
      ? {...todo, completed: !todo.completed}
      : todo
  )
```

More specifically this line

> {...todo, completed: !todo.completed}

Why is there two arguments in the true portion of the ternary operation?

What is ?

> ...

Comment: It's like `if/else` but as a single line. So the stuff after `?` will be returned if `(todo.id === action.id)` evaluates to true.

Comment: [spread syntax `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) with an object, newer than ES6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `...todo`, is the spread syntax, meaning the `completed: !todo.completed` property will be added to the existing todo object along with the previous properties. Using it you don't have to manually copy over the existing properties.

Treat it as **expanding** the 'todo' object.

Also `(todo.id === action.id)` is checking whether the `id`is same in both objects and then adding the `completed: !todo.completed` property else keeping the old object as it is.

Please check out this reference guide:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

Answer (score 2):

```
{
  ...todo,
  completed: !todo.completed
}
```

is simply making a copy of `todo` but with a new `completed` property. In this case, it's equivalent to the inverse of `todo`'s completed property. It is a plain JS Object.